# How does Weka attach class labels to a test dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree, id3

I want to use Weka in my source code to build ID3 Classifier. It should take in test data-set (without class labels) and attach the label and write it into a new file. How actually does these Class labels get attached?? which class, and function does this?

```
My train dataset:
@relation data
@attribute GENDER {M,F}
@attribute FAMILY {YES,NO}
@attribute SMOKER {YES,NO}
@attribute PASSIVESMOKER {YES,NO}
@attribute CITY {YES,NO}
@attribute CHEMICALS {YES,NO}
@attribute THERAPY {YES,NO}
@attribute PERSISTENTCOUGH {YES,NO}
@attribute CLASS {LOW,BAVG,AVG,AAVG,HIGH}
@data
M,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,LOW
M,NO,NO,NO,NO,YES,NO,NO,BAVG
M,NO,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,AAVG
M,NO,NO,YES,NO,NO,NO,NO,LOW
M,NO,NO,YES,NO,YES,NO,NO,BAVG
.....
.....
Test dataset:
@relation data
@attribute GENDER {M,F}
@attribute FAMILY {YES,NO}
@attribute SMOKER {YES,NO}
@attribute PASSIVESMOKER {YES,NO}
@attribute CITY {YES,NO}
@attribute CHEMICALS {YES,NO}
@attribute THERAPY {YES,NO}
@attribute PERSISTENTCOUGH {YES,NO}
@data
M,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,NO,?
M,NO,NO,NO,NO,YES,NO,NO,?
M,NO,NO,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,?
M,NO,NO,YES,NO,NO,NO,NO,?
```

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need an ARFF file without the class attribute as test set. After that, you can use the [AddClassification](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/AddClassification.html) filter to add the class label to all the test set instances using a specific classifier.

Comment: yeah thats right. Class labels are geting added successfully. My question is HOW does Weka do that?? I have user LOW,BAVG,AVG,AAVG,HIGH as class labels. which class/ function does this?? I need to know the flow of code inside Weka

Answer (score 0):

Weka calls the function `classifyInstance` for each test set instance.